# Divided specified columns by same value

Tags: r

I have a csv with of rows of counties that contain 50 columns of pixel counts of different different land cover types. I need to convert the pixel counts to area so I need to divide each column by 10,00. There are other columns in the CSV such as county name and state. So I need an output csv with all the original columns but the ones I specify be divded by 10,000. All the columns I need divided are next to one another in the csv (columns 4:55)

Answer (score 1):

Just select the columns `4:55` and divide by 1000 (arithmetic operations are vectorized, so there is no need to loop), and update

```
df1[4:55] <- df1[4:55]/1000
```

Then, write the data back with `write.csv`

```
write.csv(df1, "yourfile.csv", quote = FALSE, row.names = FALSE)
```

Assumptions:

`df1` is a data.frame i.e. `df1` is created by reading the data from `csv` file

```
df1 <- read.csv('yourfile.csv')
```

Comment: Thank you! I knew it had to be something simple but I kept running into dead ends searching for it.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a `tidyverse` solution

### Libraries

```
library(tidyverse)
```

### Example data

```
df <-
  matrix(100,nrow = 10,ncol = 60) %>% 
  as_tibble()
```

### Code

```
df %>% 
  mutate(across(.cols = 4:55,.fns = function(x)x/10000))
```

#### Output

```
# A tibble: 10 x 60
      V1    V2    V3    V4    V5    V6    V7    V8    V9   V10   V11   V12   V13   V14   V15   V16   V17
   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
 1   100   100   100  0.01  0.01  0.01  0.01  0.01  0.01  0.01  0.01  0.01  0.01  0.01  0.01  0.01  0.01
 2   100   100   100  0.01  0.01  0.01  0.01  0.01  0.01  0.01  0.01  0.01  0.01  0.01  0.01  0.01  0.01
 3   100   100   100  0.01  0.01  0.01  0.01  0.01  0.01  0.01  0.01  0.01  0.01  0.01  0.01  0.01  0.01
 4   100   100   100  0.01  0.01  0.01  0.01  0.01  0.01  0.01  0.01  0.01  0.01  0.01  0.01  0.01  0.01
 5   100   100   100  0.01  0.01  0.01  0.01  0.01  0.01  0.01  0.01  0.01  0.01  0.01  0.01  0.01  0.01
 6   100   100   100  0.01  0.01  0.01  0.01  0.01  0.01  0.01  0.01  0.01  0.01  0.01  0.01  0.01  0.01
 7   100   100   100  0.01  0.01  0.01  0.01  0.01  0.01  0.01  0.01  0.01  0.01  0.01  0.01  0.01  0.01
 8   100   100   100  0.01  0.01  0.01  0.01  0.01  0.01  0.01  0.01  0.01  0.01  0.01  0.01  0.01  0.01
 9   100   100   100  0.01  0.01  0.01  0.01  0.01  0.01  0.01  0.01  0.01  0.01  0.01  0.01  0.01  0.01
10   100   100   100  0.01  0.01  0.01  0.01  0.01  0.01  0.01  0.01  0.01  0.01  0.01  0.01  0.01  0.01
# ... with 43 more variables: V18 <dbl>, V19 <dbl>, V20 <dbl>, V21 <dbl>, V22 <dbl>, V23 <dbl>, V24 <dbl>,
#   V25 <dbl>, V26 <dbl>, V27 <dbl>, V28 <dbl>, V29 <dbl>, V30 <dbl>, V31 <dbl>, V32 <dbl>, V33 <dbl>,
#   V34 <dbl>, V35 <dbl>, V36 <dbl>, V37 <dbl>, V38 <dbl>, V39 <dbl>, V40 <dbl>, V41 <dbl>, V42 <dbl>,
#   V43 <dbl>, V44 <dbl>, V45 <dbl>, V46 <dbl>, V47 <dbl>, V48 <dbl>, V49 <dbl>, V50 <dbl>, V51 <dbl>,
#   V52 <dbl>, V53 <dbl>, V54 <dbl>, V55 <dbl>, V56 <dbl>, V57 <dbl>, V58 <dbl>, V59 <dbl>, V60 <dbl>
```